# MCollective: send parameters while invoking puppet

Tags: command, puppet

Is it possible to send parameters to puppet from below command

```
mco puppetd runonce
```

Answer (score 0):

You should type the following command "mco rpc puppetd runonce".
The mcollective-plugins is NOT recommend to use for puppet 3.x since there is a new puppet agent plugin under development [mcollective-puppet-agent](https://github.com/puppetlabs/mcollective-puppet-agent), you can use the following command: "mco rpc puppet runonce" or "mco puppet runonce"